# How to get week-wise data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have made a matrix report in which need to display column dynamically based upon the selection parameter. I have a selection paramter of date.

If I select Date on selection paramater as "03/01/2010" i.e. 1st March 2010then it should display like 1st March - 7th March

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you're after. If you're after the next 7 days then:

```
select * 
  from my_table
 where date_col between :my_date and :my_date + 7
```

If you want say Monday to Sunday then use the [`next_day`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/next_day.php) function:

```
select *
  from my_table
 where date_col between next_day(:my_date, 'Monday') - 7 
                    and next_day(:my_date, 'Monday')
```

Both where `:my_date` is the date your passing in.

If you're not passing in a date but a string then the first one would become, using the [`to_date`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function:

```
select *
  from my_table
 where date_col between to_date(:my_date,'dd/mm/yyy') + 7
                    and to_date(:my_date,'dd/mm/yyy')
```

and you could do something similar for the second. If you have to use `to_date` then `date_col` should have a [function-based index](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/indexes.php) on `to_date(date_col,'dd/mm/yyyy')` or if you're going to be converting it differently then that way.

Answer (score 4):

To get week-wise data rather than next-seven-days data, use the `TRUNCATE` function with the `W` argument to partition the data into calendar weeks.

```
select trunc(date '2012-01-30', 'w') from dual;

TRUNC(DATE'2012-01-
-------------------
2012-01-29 00:00:00
```

Note:  The day of the week this truncates to is dependent on NLS data - in some localizations weeks start on Sunday; in others, Monday.

Comment: Might be something to do with our database, but the above example with 'w' produced some odd results - defining instead as 'WW' seemed to work better.  Thanks!