# Select subsequence n days between date

Tags: oracle, date

I want to display records every 7 days between 2 date as following

```
select * 
from user1.report1 
where project_name = 'F1' 
and TO_DATE(report_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd') >= TO_DATE('2013/1/1', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
and (to_date(report_date,'yyyy/mm/dd') between to_date('2013/1/1','yyyy/mm/dd') + 7
                    and current_timestamp)
order BY report_date, report_time DESC
```

tried this by refrence to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068141/how-to-get-week-wise-data-in-oracle) but does not work out

Input:
started date (in this case, it is 2013/1/1 as in the statement above)

Expected Output:
records from started date(2013/1/1) until current date (1 week 1 record, if started date is fall on monday, the next record will be monday too and so on...)

Comment: Provide an input and the expected output.

Comment: What data types are your dates?

Comment: @Ben They are string, I have to convert them so I can work around with them

Comment: It boggles my mind how many questions include dates stored as strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the mod function to get every seventh day starting from the given start date e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM user1.report1 
WHERE project_name = 'F1' 
AND to_date(report_date,'yyyy/mm/dd') BETWEEN to_date('2013/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd')
                                          AND sysdate
AND mod(to_date(report_date,'yyyy/mm/dd') - to_date('2013/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd'), 7) = 0
ORDER BY report_date
       , report_time DESC
```

**EDIT**

The following query:

```
WITH report1 AS
  (SELECT 'F1' project_name
        , to_char(trunc(sysdate) - (level - 1), 'yyyy/mm/dd') report_date
   FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365)
SELECT *
FROM report1
WHERE project_name = 'F1'
AND to_date(report_date,'yyyy/mm/dd') BETWEEN to_date('2014/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd')
                                          AND sysdate
AND mod(to_date(report_date,'yyyy/mm/dd') - to_date('2014/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd'), 7) = 0
ORDER BY report_date
```

Gives the following output:

```
PROJECT_NAME REPORT_DATE
------------ -----------
F1           2014/01/01  
F1           2014/01/08  
F1           2014/01/15  
F1           2014/01/22  
F1           2014/01/29  
F1           2014/02/05  
F1           2014/02/12  
F1           2014/02/19  
F1           2014/02/26  
F1           2014/03/05  
F1           2014/03/12  
F1           2014/03/19  
F1           2014/03/26  
F1           2014/04/02  
F1           2014/04/09  
F1           2014/04/16  
F1           2014/04/23  
F1           2014/04/30  
F1           2014/05/07  
F1           2014/05/14  
F1           2014/05/21  
F1           2014/05/28  
F1           2014/06/04  
F1           2014/06/11  
F1           2014/06/18  
F1           2014/06/25  
F1           2014/07/02  
F1           2014/07/09  
F1           2014/07/16  
F1           2014/07/23  
F1           2014/07/30  
F1           2014/08/06  
F1           2014/08/13  
F1           2014/08/20  
F1           2014/08/27  
F1           2014/09/03  
F1           2014/09/10  

37 rows selected
```

i.e. with a input of a record for every day for the past year the output is a record per week starting on the specified start date and on the same day of the week as this date. This is what you appear to have asked for. If it is not what you wish for edit your question to give the records forming an input and what output you expect from this input; you may need to explain in words the rules for achieving this output.

Comment: @TicTacToe Define "does not work". An error message, if so which one? Unexpected output? then as zaratustra asked you will need to give the input and expected output.

Comment: Sorry, I got you wrong, I have been seeing my date in wrong format. I thought the month are day. Appreciate your help